# How to close open modal popup on button click?

Tags: angular

I have an `AppComponent` in which I have a login button. When the user clicks on the login button a `SigninComponent` opens as a modal popup.

How to close an open modal popup on button click?

Here is my code:

**app.component.html**

```html
<ng-template #content let-c="close" let-d="dismiss">
  <app-signin></app-signin>
</ng-template>
```

**app.component.ts**

```js
openModalPopup(content:string){
  this.modalPopup.open(content);
}
```

**modalPopup.ts**

```js
constructor(private modalService: NgbModal) { }

open(content: string) {
    this.modalService.open(content,{ centered: true }).result.then((result) => {
        this.closeResult = `Closed with: ${result}`;
    }, (reason) => {
        this.closeResult = `Dismissed ${this.getDismissReason(reason)}`;
    });
}        
getDismissReason(reason: any): string {
    if (reason === ModalDismissReasons.ESC) {
        return 'by pressing ESC';
    } else if (reason === ModalDismissReasons.BACKDROP_CLICK) {
        return 'by clicking on a backdrop';
    } else {
        return `with: ${reason}`;
    }
}
```

Help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Model popup service return opened popup reference.

```
// popupRef : NgbModalRef;    
this.popupRef = this.modalService.open(content,{ centered: true });
```

Then use the returned reference and close opened popup.
like :

```
urClickMethod(){
 this.popupRef.close();
}
```